# What is this IC in the PCB? Top marking H2K

Tags: operational-amplifier, identification

I believe them to be amplifiers, but I am unsure. Please help identify them.

[image: photo of component]

Comment: courageouslywin - Hi, The guidelines for asking identification questions are [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710). Although someone might identify that component just from the photo, it will increase the chances of you getting an answer (and reduce the chances of the question being "closed") if you supply as much detail as possible from that list e.g. details of the device where the component is used, photos of the whole original PCB, size measurements etc. Thanks. (As you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules too).

Comment: courageouslywin - Hi, Although you now have a likely answer, I'll leave my earlier comment to help inform future readers and for your general information. || You mention three ICs in the title, but your photo only shows one. If the top markings are different on the other two ICs then I recommend you add their photos too. At the moment, without seeing the other two devices, we can only guess that they look identical to the one in the photo. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson Sure, much thanks. Still learning about this website. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @courageouslywin. You may find this website : smd.yooneed.one useful for starters, however some components may overlap and you'll have to decide based on footprint and/or pin-count etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part is most likely an Analog Devices [ADA4897-1ARJZ](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4896-2_4897-1_4897-2.PDF) in a SOT-23 package.

[image]